# Codename one redirect issue

Tags: java, codenameone

I am currently using the BroswerComponent to integrate with a payment gateway. The flow relies on listening for redirects on the BrowserComponent. This is achieved this way

```
BrowserComponent c = new BrowserComponent();
c.addWebEventListener("onStart", e -> {
    String url = c.getURL();
    //process new url
});
```

This problem is that while this works fine on the Codename one simulator, it doesn't on a device (iOS and Android). It just stops redirecting after a couple of redirects without getting to the final step. I also have no such issues when I try to implement this flow with Native Android API using WebView. Redirecting is completed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by getting the current URL from the event object.

```
String url = c.getUrl();
```

was changed to

```
String  url = e.getSource().toString();
```

Comment: Did you look at `setBrowserNavigationCallback` notice that it is called in the native OS thread so it should be used with extreme caution but it's designed for very low level browser control.